# Angular $resource get method not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a simple resource like.

```
angular.module('app').factory('nmCategory', function($resource){
    var categoryResource = $resource('/api/categories/:id',{id:"@id"}, {
        update: {method: 'PUT', isArray : false},
        get: {method: 'GET' },
    });

    return categoryResource;
});
```

When I called `nmCategory.query()`, i get all the result returned. However, i am trying to filter by id. Thats to the a single record ehre id is @id. I then try `nmCategory.get({id: 1});` and to my surprise, it fails and returning

> /api/categories/1 Not found (404)

I was expecting to get my single record my id . I searched through more examples online, yet none refute what i am doing. Please how do i achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you look at your network inspector and see which url is being requested .. is it http//:localhost.../api/categories/1  ?? Where do you handle the api ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to that URL in your browser and see if it works. It probably doesn't. This is most likely a back-end issue, not an Angular issue.

Comment: Do i have to add a separate backed query for it again?  I mean i am using node and when i try adding the /api/categories/1 n the BE. The error disappear as you suggested. However , my query is not filtering. Do i have to filter again from the BE ?

Comment: Not sure I follow you. If you navigate to that URL in the browser, do you see the expected data? If so, you're already set up to handle it in node. If not, then yes, you need a route in node that knows how to handle that type of request.

Comment: No, i don't see a data, i now added a route for that. Then it disappear. You are right on this. My confusion is, previously my query just return all , i thought i should be able to filter the result by id at the front end without querying to the db again. It seems i have to query with my new parameter id i guess or do i ?

Comment: Yeah, you have to build out the back end to respond to any url you throw at it.

Comment: thanks man. Did that , it working. I think i misunderstood the ang resource a little bit before .